# How can I prevent myself from booting a certain distro in some particular hours?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, cron, manjaro, elementaryos

I have a dual boot setup: Manjaro KDE and Elementary OS.

Let's say I'd like to prevent Manjaro KDE from booting at a certain time (for example between 8:00 AM - 1:00 PM) so that only Elementary OS can be used in that particular time.

Since I think I can't act at GRUB level, Manjaro must certainly be able to boot but then some piece of software should prevent the user from logging in or making the distro unusable at that particular time.

Is this possible? What could I do?

Comment: Just an hint: for example you can put a check on the time when you boot in KDE.  If it is not passed you can change the boot default option (with zero waiting time) and reboot. Give it a look [to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43226/66388). Add a check on `crontab` and reboot if in the wrong time window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What it seems today it can not seem tomorrow `:-)`.

You should have been allowed to use date and time related commands on `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` editing `/etc/grub.d` even if they should rely on the internal PC clock, that has to be protected from users under both OSes and BIOS, as well as the possibility to boot from sources different from those two. Moreover remember that a failure of the motherboard battery may lead to a corrupt time shown by the internal clock.

Give it a look on this [ubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/317352/196535) for some more practical hints or to [this post](https://openschoolsolutions.org/set-up-scheduling-in-grub/) for a simple panorama. Hint relays on the `datehook` module and the config file (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`)

> ```
> insmod datehook
> if [ "$HOUR" -ge "8" -a "$HOUR" -lt "13" ]; then set default="0" #Manjaro KDE
> else set default="1"                                             #Elementary OS 
> fi
> ```

---

### By hands

If you cannot use the `grub` features above, you can apply a strategy

1. to preempt the logging in the wrong time forcing a reboot with a specific selection as described in [these other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43226/66388). You should put a time check in a script that has to be executed on boot. If the check is not passed you should force a reboot with a different `grub` option.
   Main steps are:

   - in the `/etc/default/grub` write/check `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`
   - Use `grub-set-default`(if you want) for the willed boot option
   - `sudo update-grub` to save it

   In the script to be run

   - `grub-reboot <entry>` with  that points to the other OS.
2. *kicking* out the people still logged in when it will arrive a black *time window*, e.g. following [the suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/1403464/257269) of davidgo adding a check in the `crontab` (but again I think it is better to write a little script  that reboots with the willed grub option or if it works directly `grub-reboot <entry>`).

Have a nice reading and trying time...

Answer (score 2):

If you can put a solytion in place for this, you can bypass it. If its to frustrate attempts by someone less knowledgeable, you can simply add a line to crontab to reboot every minute between those hours. Possibly along the lines of editing /etc/crontab and adding

```
       * 8-12 * * * root shutdown -h now
```

Comment: If you want/find useful you can give a look to the comment above (mainly the link) about how to change the `grub` behavior to minimize the rebooting.

Comment: BTW I love the approach _"to frustrate the attempts of someone less expert"_ ... or they increase their knowledge or they have to be bored to death! `:-)`